# How to split a dataframe into some dataframes according to list of row numbers?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe, I want to obtain a list of distinct dataframes which together concatenate into the original.

The separation is by indices of rows like so

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"a": np.arange(10)}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

> ```
>    a
> 0  0
> 1  1
> 2  2
> 3  3
> 4  4
> 5  5
> 6  6
> 7  7
> 8  8
> 9  9
> ```

```
separate_by = [1, 5, 6, ]
```

should give a list of

df1 =

> ```
>    a
> 0  0
> ```

df2 =

> ```
>    a
> 1  1
> 2  2
> 3  3
> 4  4
> ```

df3 =

> ```
>    a
> 5  5
> ```

df4 =

> ```
>    a
> 6  6
> 7  7
> 8  8
> 9  9
> ```

How can this be done in pandas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
separate_by = [1, 5, 6, ]
separate_by.append(len(df))
separate_by.append(0, 0)
dfs = [df.loc[separate_by[i]: separate_by[i+1]] for i in range(len(separate_by)-1)]
```

Comment: I am all for vectorization, but for my use case (very few rows), I will take readability. Thanks

Comment: @Gulzar Indeed, my proposed solution is far from being the fastest when dealing with large data sets. The other solutions will certainly fit others though.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
groups = (pd.Series(1, index=separate_by)
            .reindex(df.index,fill_value=0)
            .cumsum()
         )

out = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby(groups)}
```

then for example, `out[2]`:

```
   a
5  5
```

Similar logic:

```
groups = np.zeros(len(df))
groups[separate_by] = 1
groups = np.cumsum(groups)

out = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby(groups)}
```

Comment: can you explain the logic please? I am not following :(

Comment: @Gulzar can you print `groups` in my answer. Basically I was trying to build the group of rows by marking `1` at `separate_by`, else `0`, then do a cumsum.

Answer (score 2):

Let us try

```
d = dict(tuple(df.groupby(df.index.isin(separate_by).cumsum())))

d[0]
Out[364]: 
   a
0  0
d[2]
Out[365]: 
   a
5  5
```